# how to save the signature in amazon s3 bucket in filament php

Tags: laravel, signature, laravel-filament, filamentphp

`SignaturePad::make('signature') ->backgroundColor('rgba(255,255,255,0)') ->downloadable() ->filename('autograph') ->doneAction(fn (Action $action) => info("ddd")) ->required()`
i used this code in filamentphp but can't figure out how to store the signature file in amazon s3 bucket and i'm using this `use Saade\FilamentAutograph\Forms\Components\SignaturePad;` this package

Please help me to store the signature in amazon s3 bucket using laravel and filamentphp